# why isn't google charts rendering properly?

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

I have several Google Charts on my site, and they were working perfectly fine yesterday, but aren't working today - and I didn't change any code since yesterday.

Here is some of my relevant code:

```
import { Chart } from 'react-google-charts';
/*global google*/

getUPS(evt) {
evt.preventDefault();
fetch(url + document.getElementById("time").value)
.then(results => {
    return results.json();
 }).then(data => {
     data = data.value;
     var data2 = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data2.addColumn("string", "timestamp");
     data2.addColumn("string", "name");
     data2.addColumn("string", "trackingId");
     for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
         data2.addRow([data[i].timestamp, data[i].customEvent.name, data[i].customDimensions.trackingId]);
      }

     this.setState({
         data7: data2
     });
     console.log(data2);
     document.getElementById("datatable").style.display = "block";
     })
}

    render() {
       return (
                   <div style={{ display: 'none' }} id="tablechart" className={'chart'}>
            <Chart
                chartType="Table"
                data={this.state.data7}
                options={this.state.options2}
                width="1600px"
                height="1000px"
            /> 
            </div>
         )}
```

Comment: Any error messages in the browser console? The url you are generating may not be valid.

Comment: @trixn, there are no error messages shown, and the url is valid; I have confirmed that the data is correct by examining it with a `console.log()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't need to use a google visualization datatable.

Was able to make it work with:

```
            let data2 = [
                [
                    "time",
                    "requests"
                ]
            ]
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              data2.push([data[i].time, data[i].requests])
            }
            this.setState({data: data2});
```